# Horizontal single-page scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

Both websites demonstrate the scrolling

http://connectedkc.herokuapp.com/home/launch

http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/#about

In the source files, they both contain a content_scripts folder with a scroller.js (along with vimium_frontend and a marker.js). I assume this is not a coincidence.

I've tried jquery animate and it accomplishes the same thing but the effect is totally different.

Comment: I would like to know the answer to this too

Comment: @itcouldevenbeaboat Then bookmark the question using the star under the voting panel to the left.